# Nativescript Vue: access class functions

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm currently building an app with Nativescript and Vuejs. 
I use the Material BottomNavigationBar (https://github.com/Akylas/nativescript-material-components/blob/master/packages/nativescript-material-bottomnavigationbar/README.md).
There are two methods included i need to use:

- selectTab(index: number)
- showBadge(index: number, value?: number)

Now I need to call these methods and there is the issue. How do I do that?

My code:
**main.js**

```
import BottomNavigationBar from 'nativescript-material-bottomnavigationbar/vue';
import BottomNavigationTab from 'nativescript-material-bottomnavigationbar/vue';

Vue.use(BottomNavigationBar);
Vue.use(BottomNavigationTab);
```

**Footer.vue:**

```
<BottomNavigationBar titleVisibility="Never" activeColor="#0285ff" inactiveColor="#5c687c"
                                     backgroundColor="#f5f5f5" @tabSelected="onBottomNavigationTabSelected" row="1"
                                     class="footer" ref="navBar" :selectedTab="2">
<BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/logo.png"/>
<BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/chat.png"/>
<BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/settings.png"/>
</BottomNavigationBar>
...
mounted() {
this.$refs.navBar.nativeView.selectTab(2)
}
```

This is not working and says that nativeView is undefined.

Is there a way to access these class methods?

Regards,
Tobias

Comment: Mounted may be too early. Why don't you simply set `selectedTabIndex` on `BottomNavigationBar` instead of calling the method upon mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

It is necessary to wait until the component is loaded.

My way now:

Component:

```
<BottomNavigationBar titleVisibility="Never" activeColor="#0285ff" inactiveColor="#5c687c"
                             backgroundColor="#f5f5f5" @tabPressed="pressedNavigation" @tabSelected="pressedNavigation"
                             row="1" class="footer" ref="navBar" @loaded="loaded">
            <BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/logo.png"/>
            <BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/chat.png"/>
            <BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/settings.png"/>
</BottomNavigationBar>
```

Method:

```
 loaded(args) {
     this.loadedNavBar = true;
     this.navBar = args.object
     if (this.selectedTab !== null) this.navBar.selectTab(this.selectedTab)
  },
```

I select the index and store it in a varaible. When the component is loaded I can adjust the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a **ref="mybar"** in the tags and then find it under `this.$refs.mybar` inside your component script.

Just like what was made on [this example](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/SideDrawer/getting-started).

See [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) for more details.

Comment: Does not work. I added ```this.$refs.navBar.showBadge(1,50)``` and the result is: 
```Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.navBar.showBadge is not a function```

Answer (score 0):

Your component has yet to load when mounted gets triggered.
I'd suggest using a loaded event on your navbar component and then trigger your method.

```
<BottomNavigationBar titleVisibility="Never" activeColor="#0285ff" inactiveColor="#5c687c"
                                 backgroundColor="#f5f5f5" @tabSelected="onBottomNavigationTabSelected" row="1" @loaded="onNavbarLoaded"
                                 class="footer" ref="navBar" :selectedTab="2">

    <BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/logo.png"/>
    <BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/chat.png"/>
    <BottomNavigationTab icon="~/assets/images/settings.png"/>
</BottomNavigationBar>

onNavbarLoaded(evt) {
    this.$refs.navBar.nativeView.selectTab(2);
    // I am not sure if you actually have to easy nativeView..
    this.$refs.navBar.selectTab(2);
}
```